# Scala3 fails with unable to resolve dependent type

Tags: scala, scala-3

I am trying to implement `Zip` on a custom type that I have. I tried lot of different implementation none of them seem to work out. This one fails to figure out the `X.State` saying the class file is missing from classpath. I dont understand why it fails like that.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

```scala
object ZipAll:
  trait Pull[Output]:
    type State
    def initial(): State
    def pull(context: Context, state: State): Timestampped[Output]

  type OutputOf[P <: Pull[_]] = P match
    case Pull[output] => output

  type StateOf[P <: Pull[_]] = P#State


  inline def stateOf[Outputs <: Tuple, Pulls <: Tuple.Map[Outputs, Pull]](pulls: Pulls): Tuple.Map[Pulls, StateOf] = pulls.map[StateOf]{
    [X] =>
      (pull: X) => 
        summonFrom {
          case asPull: (pull.type <:< Pull[_]) => 
            val p = asPull(pull)
            summonFrom {
              case asResult: (p.State =:= StateOf[X]) => 
                asResult(p.initial())
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: _"achieve this"_ - I'm somehow struggling to understand what exactly _"this"_ is that you're attempting to implement. Are you referring to some common typeclass _"Zip"_, or what is all that about?